# Flutter: Pan, Rotate and Scale a positioned widget within a stack

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to seamlessly move, rotate and scale a widget that is positioned within a stack. Since Pan and Scale Gesture Recognizers cannot be used together within the GestureDetector widget, I am trying to use scale to derive offset.

However, the object scales in a weird way when attempting to pan and scale at the same time, and the object scales and moves away of my pinching fingers. If done separately, they behave normally.

Based on a couple of posts, I've attempted the following:

```
    import 'package:app/features/_shared_widgets/vertical_spacing.dart';
    import 'package:app/model/piece.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:transparent_image/transparent_image.dart';
    import 'dart:ui' as ui;

    class MoveableStackItem extends StatefulWidget {
      final Piece piece;
      MoveableStackItem({@required this.piece});

      @override
      State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
        return _MoveableStackItemState();
      }
    }

    class _MoveableStackItemState extends State<MoveableStackItem> {
      double _xPosition;
      double _yPosition;
      double _rotation;
      double _scale;

      Offset _startingFocalPoint;
      Offset _previousOffset;
      double _previousScale;

      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();

    _xPosition = widget.piece.position.x;
    _yPosition = widget.piece.position.y;
    _rotation = widget.piece.position.angle;
    _scale = widget.piece.position.scale;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
      top: _yPosition,
      left: _xPosition,
      child: GestureDetector(
        onScaleStart: (ScaleStartDetails details) {
          setState(() {
            _startingFocalPoint = details.focalPoint;
            _previousOffset = Offset(_xPosition, _yPosition);
            _previousScale = _scale;
          });
        },
        onScaleUpdate: (ScaleUpdateDetails details) {
          setState(() {
            _scale = _previousScale * details.scale;

            // Ensure that item under the focal point stays in the same place despite zooming
            final Offset normalizedOffset =
                (_startingFocalPoint - _previousOffset) / _previousScale;
            _xPosition = (details.focalPoint - normalizedOffset * _scale).dx;
            _yPosition = (details.focalPoint - normalizedOffset * _scale).dy;
            if (details.rotation != 0) _rotation = details.rotation;
          });
        },
        child: Transform.rotate(
          angle: _rotation,
          child: Transform.scale(
            scale: _scale,
            child: Container(
              width: 200,
              child: FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
                fit: BoxFit.contain,
                image: widget.piece.imageUrl,
                placeholder: kTransparentImage,
                placeholderErrorBuilder: (context, url, error) =>
                    Icon(Icons.error),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I also tried Transform.translate with a position of top: 0, and left: 0 with the same results. Can anyone detect anything that might be upsetting the translation?

Comment: As a workaround, I decided to block translation unless there is no scale by adding: if (_scale == _previousScale) { //apply translation }. However, this doesn't quite solve my problem of doing all at the same time

Comment: https://github.com/pskink/matrix_gesture_detector/blob/master/lib/matrix_gesture_detector.dart

Comment: any solution to this yet? i am also looking for something like this